# Mockito argument captor and only()

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I found, that whenever I use verify with only() - to check that invocation was just one time - ArgumentCaptor can't capture a value (I have null in value).

For instance: verify(delegate, only()).call(captor.capture());

What are the reasons for it? Or it is just a bug?

Comment: Tested this using Mockito 1.9.0, and it seems to work just fine. Are you sure you're not just invoking `call()` with null as an argument? Also note that `only()` checks whether that is the only invocation on the mock, not just of the verified method.

Comment: I also tested this with Mockito 1.9.5 and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `only()` is actually doing, but `Mockito.times(1)` works, while the `only()` fails.

My guess is when you call `Mockito.when` initially it's counted as the first invocation in case of `only()`, but not in `Mockito.times`